# What do sandbox games usually do when generating new terrains?

Tags: terrain

I am trying to make a minecraft. In my game, when the player moves to the boundary, new chunks will be generated.

What I do is creating new chunks in my main thread and generating a new VBO to store them. But I find that it's quite inefficient and you can obviously feel the FPS is decreasing.

What do these kinds of games usually do when generating new terrains? Do they use multi-threads or some specific efficient algorithms or compute shaders (I still don't know much about OpenGL)? I once tried to generate my new terrains in another thread. But I found I can't use GL operation to generate VBO in another thread. I am thinking about pre-generated some VBOs in my main thread. Is that the right way?

I want to know what most people do in this situation.

Comment: https://0fps.net/2012/01/14/an-analysis-of-minecraft-like-engines/ Here's an useful link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, Minecraft actually uses immediate mode with Display Lists to render the chunks. They generate the chunk using a noise algorithm, then use greedy meshing to combine neighbor voxel faces, and lastly, throw it all into a display list so a chunk can be drawn with a single draw call.